Application of inverse function theorem.
I am working on this problem.
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function given by $f(x) = x + g(x)$, where $g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$. Suppose that for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $||g'(0)v|| < 1$. Show that $f$ is locally invertible near $0$.
Now, in order to apply the inverse function theorem, I must show that $\det f'(0) \neq 0$. Note first that $f'(x) = I_n + g'(x)$. Suppose that $\det f'(0) = 0$. Then $\det (g'(0) + I_n) = 0$. This implies that $g'(0) + I_n$ is not invertible. And then I'm stuck.
I don't think this is the right approach. I would like to use the condition $||g'(0)v|| < 1$ to show that $g'(0) = 0$ and then I would get that $\det f'(0) = \det I_n = 1 \neq 0$.
Any help is kindly appreciated.

Fix any $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $t>0$. Then $t|g'(0)v|= |g'(0)(tv)|<1$, hence $|g'(0)v|< 1/t$ and $t \to \infty$ shows $|g'(0)v|=0$. Since $v$ was arbitrary you get $g'(0)=0$.

This solves it. Thank you.

Is it sufficient for the condition to hold for unit $v$. If $f'(0)v = 0$ then $v=-g'(0)v $ and so $|v| = |g'(0)v| < |v|$, a contradiction.

If $|g'(0)v| <1$ for all $v$ then clearly $g'(0) = 0$.

Perhaps you meant $|g'(0)v|<|v|$ for every $v\neq 0.$  This implies $I+g'(0)$ is invertible.
